# How to replace initState in Stateful Widget with provider mode and replace stateless to stateful

Tags: flutter, dart

How to use `initState()` in provider mode instead of using statefull widget,

this is the provider class I have:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class NavigationBBarData extends ChangeNotifier {
  int currentIndex = 0;
  PageController pageController;

  final GlobalKey<FormFieldState<String>> orderFormKey = GlobalKey();

  void pageChanged(int index) {
    currentIndex = index;
    notifyListeners();
  }

  void animateToPage() {
    pageController.animateToPage(currentIndex,
        duration: Duration(milliseconds: 500), curve: Curves.linear);
    notifyListeners();
  }
}
```

and this is the Stateful widget I have which contains the `initState()` method:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:ipetv1/providers/navigation_bbar_data.dart';
import 'package:ipetv1/widgets/ipet_bottom_nav_bar.dart';
import 'package:ipetv1/widgets/ipet_page_view.dart';
import 'package:provider/provider.dart';

class IPetNavHomeScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _IPetNavHomeScreenState createState() => _IPetNavHomeScreenState();
}

class _IPetNavHomeScreenState extends State<IPetNavHomeScreen> {
  @override
  void initState() {
    Provider.of<NavigationBBarData>(context, listen: false).pageController =
        PageController(
      initialPage:
          Provider.of<NavigationBBarData>(context, listen: false).currentIndex,
      keepPage: true,
    );
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Stack(
      children: [
        IPetPageView(),
        Positioned(
          left: 0,
          right: 0,
          bottom: 0,
          child: IPetBottomNavBar(),
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

So I want to use here the stateless widget instead of the Stateful one using provider statemanagement..

Comment: I don't know how to do it in Provider.  I've already moved beyond that to RiverPod, and it's trivial in RiverPod.

Comment: @RandalSchwartz I see that I can do it with provider in the docs, but can't get the way... I am sure there's a way to do this, btw thanks for your support :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I haven't tested the code but I imagine something like this should work. When the code is run, it will run the build method which will then search up the widget tree for your provider. Once it finds the provider it will set it to `navigationBBarData`, then you can access the providers `PageController` and set it to what you like.

```
class IPetNavHomeScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    NavigationBBarData navigationBBarData =
        Provider.of<NavigationBBarData>(context, listen: false);
    navigationBBarData.PageController = PageController(
      initialPage: navigationBBarData.currentIndex,
      keepPage: true,
    );
    return Stack(
      children: [
        IPetPageView(),
        Positioned(
          left: 0,
          right: 0,
          bottom: 0,
          child: IPetBottomNavBar(),
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
}
```